# How to add looping condition for selenium java code

Tags: java, loops, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to automate links in my website. I want to pass xpath values once in each iteration of loop.  So that I can minimize my coding
    public class Popup 
    {

```
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  //private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.example.com/info.php";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testPopup() throws Exception {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='info-list']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/a[2]/i")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='info-list']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/a[3]/i")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='info-list']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/a[4]/i")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='info-list']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/a[5]/i")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
for(int j=2; j<=5; j++) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='info-list']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/a["+j+"]/i")).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sanchit Khera Try this one :

```
int i = 0;

    //extract the link texts of each link element
    for (WebElement e : linkElements) 
    {
        linkTitles[i] = e.getText();
        i++;
    }

    //Test each link
    for (String t : linkTitles) 
    {               
            // Titles Click 
            driver.findElement(By.linkText(t)).click();
```